# MySQL how to pivot data to show users in database belonging to multiple groups

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I'm trying to write an export script for Modx that will show members who belong to multiple groups,  I've gotten this far:

```
select u.id, u.username, u.primary_group, mgn.name,
    CASE WHEN mgn.name = 'Administrator' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS `Administrator`,
    CASE WHEN mgn.name = 'Members' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS `Members`,
    CASE WHEN mgn.name = 'Privileged Members' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS `Privileged Members`
from modx_users u
left join modx_member_groups mg on mg.member = u.id
left join modx_membergroup_names mgn on mgn.id = mg.user_group
#where u.username = 'administrator'
#group by u.username
limit 10000;
```

it does show the user group membership as true or false in a query, but if a user belongs to multiple groups the query will return 3 rows. If I uncomment the group by condition, it will not show TRUE for multiple groups if the member belongs to more than one group.

It is also incredibly slow. 10++ seconds on a database of about 10,000 users.

How can I fix this to show each user on a single row (in interest of exporting to CSV)  and show multiple group membership?

Comment: What indexes do you have on your tables?

Comment: both tables have an ID primary key,  member groups has a role and rank field indexed (which I don't need)  membergroup_names has 'parent' & 'rank' indexed, also not useful to me.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  If you have multiple membership, are you using `SET`?  Or multiple rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve the performance you may need to add appropriate indexes to the tables. This query should do what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
  id, username, primary_group,
  CASE MAX(`Administrator`) WHEN 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS `Administrator`,
  CASE MAX(`Members`) WHEN 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS `Members`,
  CASE MAX(`Privileged Members`) WHEN 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS `Privileged Members`
FROM (
  SELECT u.id, u.username, u.primary_group,
    CASE WHEN mgn.name = 'Administrator' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `Administrator`,
    CASE WHEN mgn.name = 'Members' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `Members`,
    CASE WHEN mgn.name = 'Privileged Members' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `Privileged Members`
  FROM modx_users u
  LEFT JOIN modx_member_groups mg on mg.member = u.id
  LEFT JOIN modx_membergroup_names mgn on mgn.id = mg.user_group
) z
GROUP BY id, username, primary_group
```

Comment: yes - it does, thanks.  still slow.  I can swap out the mgn.name for mg.user_group and match against an ID in the mgn table, mg.user_group = 1   but n o speed improvements as the mg.user_group column is not indexed.   I could certainly add an index, but not sure if future updates would remove it?

Comment: By using mg.user_group instead of mgn.name it appears you can eliminate the join with modx_membergroup_names table altogether. If so, that should help performance.

Comment: yes - yes, we can do that. it does work, but does not have an appreciable effect on the speed - still around 10 seconds on a database of about 10,000 users.

Comment: A compound index on (mg.member, mg.user_group) would probably help a lot. It might also help a little to take username and primary_group out of the grouping, though I might expect MySQL to optimize that itself.

Comment: mm adding indexes makes this much less portable from system to system and through upgrades.   Just tested it against live data (different server) the results took 140 seconds to come back.  I think I need another solution.  Wondering if I can just select the group membership IDs as an array and deal with that in php when I convert to CSV ....

Comment: Yes you might be better off just querying the raw data and processing it yourself, if you need the results for all users anyway.

Comment: yes a straight up join on the tables concerned: select * from modx_users u LEFT JOIN modx_member_groups mg on mg.member = u.id; still takes 20 seconds in DEV times out in production,

Comment: I'm thinking group concat just the member_groups table into an array and merge it with another result set from the modx_users table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that removes the extra join (assuming 101, 102 and 103 are the ID values for Administrator, Members and Privileged Members, respectively) and removes username and primary_group from the grouping. It ought to perform a little better than the original, all things being equal:

```
SELECT
  uuu.id,
  uuu.username,
  uuu.primary_group,
  `Administrator`,
  `Members`,
  `Privileged Members`
FROM
  modx_users uuu
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      z.id,
      CASE MAX(`Administrator`) WHEN 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS `Administrator`,
      CASE MAX(`Members`) WHEN 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS `Members`,
      CASE MAX(`Privileged Members`) WHEN 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS `Privileged Members`
    FROM
    (
      SELECT u.id,
        CASE WHEN mg.user_group = 101 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `Administrator`,
        CASE WHEN mg.user_group = 102 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `Members`,
        CASE WHEN mg.user_group = 103 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `Privileged Members`
      FROM modx_users u
      LEFT JOIN modx_member_groups mg on mg.member = u.id
    ) z
    GROUP BY z.id
  ) zz on uuu.id=zz.id
```